# How can I loop from a saved data as cart format?

Tags: php, serialization, opencart

I've been working on an Opencart site for few days. The old developer saved some data in a old table where there is one column named `cart`. In this column, I've got data which allows me (I guess) to display which product has been ordered, the quantities and the price. I need to make a `foreach()` loop and display this information. How can i do it ? One example of a saved data: `a:3:{i:144;s:1:"2";i:172;i:2;i:193;i:1;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's called a [serialized array](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php).  At the most basic level, you can [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) it and loop through the cart data like this:

```php
$cart = unserialize('a:3:{i:144;s:1:"2";i:172;i:2;i:193;i:1;}');
foreach ($cart as $product_id => $quantity) {
    echo "Product ID: $product_id\n";
    echo "Quantity: $quantity\n\n";
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Product ID: 144
Quantity: 2

Product ID: 172
Quantity: 2

Product ID: 193
Quantity: 1
```

If there are options involved things get more complicated and rather than replicate cart library functions you're better off just restoring the cart and iterating over the products using Opencart's core directly:

```php
// query the database
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT cart FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "table_name WHERE customer_id = '123'")->row;

// unserialize the resulting row
$cart = unserialize($query['cart']);

// initialize the session array
$this->session->data['cart'] = array();

// restore cart to session
foreach ($cart as $key => $value) {
    $this->session->data['cart'][$key] = $value;
}

// loop through products
foreach ($this->cart->getProducts() as $product) {
    print_r($product);
}
```